# Why isn't Ubuntu Tweak's Janitor working?

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-tweak

Whenever I use Ubuntu tweak's janitor to clear caches and I select all the files I want to delete and click "clean" nothing happens. (See the screenshot below) This has only began since I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04.

[image]

Comment: Did you re-enable the ppa (it is deactivated after upgrade) and install the newest version?

Comment: No I haven't. How would I do that?

Comment: Open Software-Updates. In settings, go to "Other Software" and enable the ppa. Then run `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As Donarsson pointed out in his comment, I think you just need to update. Ubuntu Tweak works fine for me in 13.04.

In a terminal, type these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: This failed to fix the problem. I am still unable to clean my system with janitor

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is purging the program and reinstalling it. Sorry that didn't work out.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either.