# Alternative of CCleaner in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, firefox, startup, cleanup

Is there any alternative software of CCleaner in Ubuntu 13.10. My laptop is running very slow, and Firefox also running slow and unresponsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bleachbit is a good alternative for linux and will allow you to clean program clutter and system clutter to tidy up things like logs, caches and thumbnail libraries grown too huge...  It can be found in the Software Centre...

Answer (score 1):

I second the Bleachbit program. It's a good alternative, but don't do what I did and accidentally check the "wipe free disk space" option. :P

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Tweak](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak) is a tool for Ubuntu that makes it easy to configure your system and desktop settings.

It has a janitor. (may be you need this fix if not fixed upstream yet: [Ubuntu tweak and Mozilla (firefox and thunderbird) cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375831/ubuntu-tweak-and-mozilla-firefox-and-thunderbird-cache))

Its stable ppa here: [ppa:tualatrix/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ppa)